# Combine two tables using collect and table

Tags: stata

I built a sample description table in Stata 17 and have recently switched over to Stata 18. I want to combine two tables. The first table summarizes the sample selection criterion and tells me how many people are included in the regressions. The second table summarizes the sex and age only for those people included.

My MRE looks like this at the moment:

```
clear all

input id inclusion age sex
1 1 35 0
2 1 56 1
3 0 78 1
3 1 43 1
4 0 3 0
5 1 40 0 
6 1 5 0
7 0 55 1
8 1 31 0
9 1 26 0
10 0 34 1
11 0 45 1
12 0 67 0
end

putdocx begin
table () () (), statistic(mean inclusion) statistic(sd inclusion) statistic(min inclusion) statistic(max inclusion) nformat(%6.2f mean sd)
    collect layout (var) (result)
    collect label levels result mean "Mean" sd "SD" min "Min." max "Max.", modify
    putdocx pagebreak
    putdocx paragraph, style(Heading1)
    putdocx text ("Table 2: Sample description")
    putdocx collect
    
table ( ) () () if inclusion == 1, /*
 */ statistic(mean age) statistic(sd age) statistic(min age) statistic(max age) /*
 */ statistic(mean sex) statistic(sd sex) statistic(min sex) statistic(max sex)
    collect layout (var) (result)
    collect label levels result mean "Mean" sd "SD" min "Min." max "Max.", modify
    putdocx collect
    putdocx save Tables, append
```

I have tried using the collect combine command but the combination does not show the right order of the variables. The goal is to create one table to put into Word using putdocx.

```
* putdocx begin
table () () (), statistic(mean inclusion) statistic(sd inclusion) statistic(min inclusion) statistic(max inclusion) nformat(%6.2f mean sd)
    collect layout (var) (result)
    collect label levels result mean "Mean" sd "SD" min "Min." max "Max.", modify
    collect rename Table table21
    
table ( ) () () if inclusion == 1, /*
 */ statistic(mean age) statistic(sd age) statistic(min age) statistic(max age) /*
 */ statistic(mean sex) statistic(sd sex) statistic(min sex) statistic(max sex)
    collect layout (var) (result)
    collect label levels result mean "Mean" sd "SD" min "Min." max "Max.", modify
    collect rename Table table22
    collect combine Table2 = table21 table22, layout(right) style(right)
    collect preview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in the Stata-forum by [Jeff Pitblado](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1712111-combine-two-tables-using-collect-and-table):

Copy-pasted answer here:
If you do not want to respecify the `collect layout with var[inclusion age sex]`, then you can control the order and selection of the levels of var using collect style autolevels. Here is how using the above example

```
collect style autolevels var inclusion age sex
```

Here is the resulting table

```
. collect preview

----------------------------------------
          |   Mean      SD   Min.   Max.
----------+-----------------------------
inclusion |   0.54    0.52      0      1
age       |  33.71   15.89      5     56
sex       |   0.29    0.49      0      1
----------------------------------------
```

My own remark: The first solution comes right after the combine command and should look like this:

```
collect layout (var[inclusion age sex]) (result)
```